# Get Name value from sub table with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the below datatable using JavaScript and looking to find a possible way to get the LineType Name property instead of the "invoiceLineTypeId" column. The table that stores the Name property is InvoiceLineTypes and the correlating ID's.

I am very new to JavaScript but my thoughts is I would most likely have to render invoiceLineTypeID and do some type of jquery lookup to that table, then display back into the datatable. Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this?

```js
var table = $("#invoiceLineItems").DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: "/api/InvoiceDetails/" + $('#InvoiceMaster_Id').val(),
    dataSrc: ""
  },
  columns: [{
    data: "invoiceLineTypeId"
  }, {
    data: "description"
  }, {
    data: "partNumber"
  }, {
    data: "quantity"
  }, {
    data: "chargeAmount"
  }, {
    data: "totalAmount"
  }, {
    data: "id",
    render: function(data) {
      return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-invoicedetails-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
    }
  }]
});
```

Here is InvoiceDetails Class

```
public class InvoiceDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public Guid AccountGUID { get; set; }

    public int SubAccountID { get; set; }

    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public InvoiceLineType InvoiceLineType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Line Type")]
    public int InvoiceLineTypeId { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal ChargeAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

    public decimal AvgTotal { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is the column you want to  display already included in the data coming back from the AJAX request to the `"/api/InvoiceDetails/" + $('#InvoiceMaster_Id').val()` endpoint? If so, you just need to amend the `data` property to match the field name. If not, you need to change your server side code to return the value, then change the `data` property.

Comment: I currently return the contents like this:  return _context.InvoiceDetails.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<InvoiceDetails, InvoiceDetailsDto>).Where(c => c.InvoiceId == id);

Comment: I am not 100% certain what you are suggesting

Comment: does your `InvoiceDetails` model have a `LineTypeName` field or `LineType` property? If not, you'll need to add it and include it in your automapper config

Comment: It does not, I will add it and try it out.

Comment: I have added in my InvoiceDetails class that does included the InvoiceLineTypeName

Comment: Firstly your ajax call should return a json data, this is very important. Next, you can use your backend to populate key-value pair for json as per your need (eg: LineType instead of invoiceLineTypeId). Besides, in the DataTable you can also make use of the column definition to show your preffered column by index number. Plenty of examples matching your requirements are at official documentation of DataTable: https://datatables.net/manual/ajax

Comment: @Ren Please post your comment as an answer. I will give you credit. After following documentation on https://datatables.net/manual/ajax I was able to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your ajax call should return a json data, this is very important. Next, you can use your backend to populate key-value pair for json as per your need (eg: LineType instead of invoiceLineTypeId).

Besides, in the DataTable you can also make use of the column definition to show your preferred column by index number. Plenty of examples matching your requirements are at official documentation of DataTable: datatables.net/manual/ajax